# Can there be more than one active state in a UML state machine

Tags: state-machine

I understand that there can be orthogonal regions in a composite state running in parallel at the same.
Can there be more than one active state at any time in a UML state machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there can be more than 1 active state whenever a run-to-completion step is completed. Actually there can be a whole tree of active states:

As you mentioned, there can be active states in orthogonal regions of a composite state. Also composite states can be recursively nested. This means that if a nested state is active, all its ancestors are active as well. Thus the combination of orthogonal regions and nested composite states can lead to a whole tree of active states.

The ***UML Superstructure Specification, v2.4.1*** explains it like this (page 564 in chapter 15.3.11 State):

> **Active state configurations**
>
> In a hierarchical state machine more than
>   one state can be active at the same time. If the state machine is in a
>   simple state that is contained in a composite state, then all the
>   composite states that either directly or transitively contain the
>   simple state are also active. Furthermore, since the state machine as
>   a whole and some of the composite states in this hierarchy may be
>   orthogonal (i.e., containing regions), the current active “state” is
>   actually represented by a set of trees of states starting with the
>   top-most states of the root regions down to the innermost active
>   substate. We refer to such a state tree as a state configuration.

There can be a exception if you are nit-picky:

If the state machine terminated, there is of course no active state left at all and thus there cannot be multiple active states at that point.

**Note**

The UML Superstructure Specification, v2.4.1 is ***the*** document to check if you have questions like this.